# React native restore the original link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this link in my component when the browser enter http://localhost:19006/index.html?a2V2aW50cmluaWRhZDUxMkBnb, how can i remove the **/index.html?a2V2aW50cmluaWRhZDUxMkBnb** when it enter the another component?

```
      if(response.status==200){
          MySwal.fire(
            'Successful!',
            'Your Password Changed successfully',
            'success'
          )
          console.log(window.location.protocol)
          console.log(window.location.hash)
          console.log(window.location.pathname)
          window.location.href=''
          //window.location.origin
          navigation.replace('Login')
```

Comment: Are you using any routing methods?

Comment: this http://localhost:19006/index.html?a2V2aW50cmluaWRhZDUxMkBnb from the google that if the user clicks it, it will go to the change password, and if the user submit their new password, it will go to Login component, i just want that it will clean the url after the finish changing their password

Comment: Check if this works https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the url, you can use the ***history*** interface which allows to modify the browser session history which are the pages loaded in the browser tab.
Now there are many methods in History interface. You can find all of them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) .
**replacestate()** method is the one which you should be looking for in this case I believe.

The following method can be used to change the url:

```
const handleChange = () => {
  let newUrl = "/login";
  window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, newUrl);
};
```

You can call this method whenever the user has submitted the password. I'd suggest you to go through the docs to understand all these arguments passed in detail.

Please mark this answer as accepted if it solves your issue.